# Lua: how do I point to an array item through a variable?

Tags: pointers, lua

For example:

```
local array = {2, 6}
local value = array[1]

...
value = 4 -- Intended: change the value in the original array
...

print(array[1]) -- Will print 2, not 4 as intended
```

Is this possible? I ask because I'm working on an graphics API and I want to be able to do `color = something` instead of `frag.data[1] = something` on the shaders, it looks a lot better and it's easier to use and understand.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong on your side. i copied and pasted your code and it prints 4.

Comment: Well, didn't know about that! I changed the code; does this still work?

Comment: Now it won't, since you are copying by value. Only tables get copied by reference.

Comment: See, that's what I'm talking about; I want to be able to do that

Comment: Unless you change your implementation to use tables, then it won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. Lua `number` type is value, not pointer, but you can do something like `array = {{2}, {6}}`, then

```
local array = {{2}, {6}}
local value = array[1]
value[1] = 4
print(value[1])
```